# Bitbucket API read RAW file from branch with Access Code

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an issue accessing a branch on Private Bitbucket Repo using an Access Token.

Works fine using master, but I have no idea how to access a branch.

For example:
Accessing master is OK:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/repo/src/master/template.json?&access_token=gHmDP4e4XeBQUrmFXTGWPC4qVZEfv_JGZnXt61NGfEH2O4OeiYGHeCL0a8rwLVFasjJ0UBHcne-r2myBsGk=
```

Tried the following to access branch feature/project/code:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/repo/src/master/template.json?at=refs%2Fheads%2Ffeature%2Fproject%2Fcode&access_token=gHmDP4e4XeBQUrmFXTGWPC4qVZEfv_JGZnXt61NGfEH2O4OeiYGHeCL0a8rwLVFasjJ0UBHcne-r2myBsGk=
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/repo/src/master/template.json?at=refs/heads/feature/project/code&access_token=gHmDP4e4XeBQUrmFXTGWPC4qVZEfv_JGZnXt61NGfEH2O4OeiYGHeCL0a8rwLVFasjJ0UBHcne-r2myBsGk=
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/repo/src/feature/project/code/template.json?access_token=gHmDP4e4XeBQUrmFXTGWPC4qVZEfv_JGZnXt61NGfEH2O4OeiYGHeCL0a8rwLVFasjJ0UBHcne-r2myBsGk=
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's due to your branch naming decisions and the URL parsing regex.

You can use instead a revision code following this URL schema:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/src/{revision}/{path}
```

As in example:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/repo/src/{commit hash for head in feature/project/code/}/template.json?&access_token=blablabla
```

[Here docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/src-resources-296095214.html)

**EDIT**

In alternative you could use a branch name without slashes.

Comment: Thanks I do know that, but the problem is I need to use a name i.e features/project/code that doesn’t change. I’m using Nested ARM templates in VSTS with CI/CD pipelines. I can’t use a ever changing commit code.

Comment: just offered an alternative

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/repo/src/feature%2Fproject%2Fcode/template.json?access_token=gHmDP4e4XeBQUrmFXTGWPC4qVZEfv_JGZnXt61NGfEH2O4OeiYGHeCL0a8rwLVFasjJ0UBHcne-r2myBsGk=
```

Comment: All good - I found the problem. Need to use: `https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/user/repo/raw/feature/project/code/template.json?access_token=gHmDP4e4XeBQUrmFXTGWPC4qVZEfv_JGZnXt61NGfEH2O4OeiYGHeCL0a8rwLVFasjJ0UBHcne-r2myBsGk=`

Answer (score 0):

The correct api to use is https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0 using the following uri:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/user/repo/raw/feature/project/code/template.json?access_token=gHmDP4e4XeBQUrmFXTGWPC4qVZEfv_JGZnXt61NGfEH2O4OeiYGHeCL0a8rwLVFasjJ0UBHcne-r2myBsGk=
```

Thanks to all you responded.

Comment: Anyone know the correct api to use now that V1 APIs are disabled?