# How to download a file from Bitbucket using release branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to download a file from release branch from bitbucket but due to '/' in name it is not allowing me to download a file . API is working fine for all other branches only getting error for feature and release branch.
i tried with commit hash which is working fine but i can't change commit hash again and again in the code so i need permanent solution, is there any api or way to download a file
API i am using
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/workspace/repo/src/branch/file.txt?raw.
Check the solution from this but 1.0 api is deprecated now [Bitbucket API read RAW file from branch with Access Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804521/bitbucket-api-read-raw-file-from-branch-with-access-code)

Comment: So the problem is the / in the branch name? Isn't this the same known issue addressed here? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-REST-API-reference-branches-with-forward-slash-in-name/qaq-p/1899723 And here? https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-9969

Comment: yeah , it seems we can't do much here other  than making 2 api calls , first to get commit id and second with that commit to get the file